# Symfony Doctrine : fetch a collection persisted as array

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I have two entities `Modules` and `Orders` where One order have Many modules and I'm wondering how to fetch an array collection of modules persisted as follow:

```
Table: Orders

id | modules | user_id | ... | created_at          |
----------------------------------------------------
1  | [2,6,5] | 12      | ... | 2018-07-28 00:00:00 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see my modules are persisted as array. So after that how can I make Doctrine (with Symfony) to get my modules

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a ManyToOne relationShip ... as I know, we never store an array in database.

in your example order can have many modules and module can have just one order ... 
in this case order called owning side and module called invers side ... 
and module keep id of order ...

look at this example

Table: Orders

```
id | user_id | ... | created_at          |
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 12      | ... | 2018-07-28 00:00:00 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Table: Modules

```
id | order_id | ... | created_at          |
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | ... | 2018-07-28 00:00:00 |
----------------------------------------------------
2  | 1        | ... | 2018-07-29 00:00:00 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

you must write your code like this...

Order Class

```
class Order implements OrderInterface
{

     /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Module", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $modules;

     /**
     * Don't forget initial your collection property 
     * Order constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->modules = new ArrayCollection();
    }

        /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getModules(): Collection
    {
        return $this->modules;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleInterface $module
     */
    public function addModule(ModuleInterface $module): void
    {
        if ($this->getModules()->contains($module)) {

            return;
        } else {

            $this->getModules()->add($module);
            $module->setOrder($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleInterface $module
     */
    public function removeModule(ModuleInterface $module): void
    {
        if (!$this->getModules()->contains($module)) {

            return;
        } else {

            $this->getModules()->removeElement($module);
            $module->removeOrder($this);
        }
    }
}
```

Module Class

```
class Module implements ModuleInterface
{
    /**
     * @var OrderInterface
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Order", mappedBy="modules", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $order;

    /**
    * @param OrderInterface $order
    */
    public function setOrder(OrderInterface $order) 
    {

        $this->order = order;
    }

    public function getOrder(): OrderInterface
    {
        return $this->order;
    }
}
```

when you persist order object by doctrine... doctrine handle this and create items

Comment: it's a bit the same approach I adopted finaly. It would've been realy nice if my first thought was possible. Anyway, thx!